# While loop not checking the condition in shell

Tags: shell

I Was trying the exponential backoff algorithm with the shell. But When I am passing the pending as the parameter, Its running the never ending loop?

```
#!/bin/bash
MAX_RETRIES=5
retries=0
status=$1
while [ $retries -le  $MAX_RETRIES ];
#while
     echo  $retries
        retries=$(( $retries + 1 ))
do
sleep $(( 1^$retries* 1))
        if [[ "$status" == "success" ]]; then
        echo "success"
        break;
        elif [[ "$status" == "pending" ]]; then
        echo "pending"
        else
        echo "I am else."
        fi
        echo "Retries in do $retries"
echo "after do"; done
```

Any idea?

Comment: Have you tried putting the do directly after the while (before Echo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to break out of the loop is for `$status` to be `success`.  This is because the result of the assignment will be true value in the loop head and the loop will be infinite.

Your loop:

```
while [ some test ]; echo 'something'; retries=$(( $retries + 1 )); do
    loop body
done
```

Instead, move the `echo` and assignment into the loop:

```
#!/bin/bash

MAX_RETRIES=5
retries=0
status="$1"

while [ "$retries" -le "$MAX_RETRIES" ]; do
    echo "$retries"
    retries=$(( retries + 1 ))
    sleep $(( 1^retries * 1))

    if [[ "$status" == "success" ]]; then
        echo "success"
        break;
    elif [[ "$status" == "pending" ]]; then
        echo "pending"
    else
        echo "I am else."
    fi

    echo "Retries in do $retries"
done

echo "done."
```

Or, with `case .. esac`:

```
#!/bin/bash

MAX_RETRIES=5
retries=0
status="$1"

while [ "$retries" -le "$MAX_RETRIES" ]; do
    echo "$retries"
    retries=$(( retries + 1 ))
    sleep $(( 1^retries * 1))

    case "$status" in
        success)
            echo "success"
            break ;;
        pending)
            echo "pending" ;;
    esac

    echo "Retries in do $retries"
done

echo "done."
```

Comment: Is there any workaround by which I can run this loop until Its status==success? I can write a variable which will get the current status of the API call inside the loop.

Comment: @MohitKumar Yes, you already run until `$status` is `success`, so it would be a simple matter of either changing the string `success` to `completed`, or adding an equivalent test for `completed` as for `success`. Or, you can have `while [ old test ] && [ "$status" -ne "completed" ]; do`.

Comment: `while [ old test ] && [ "$status" -ne "completed" ];` This would be great.

Comment: @MohitKumar Sorry, that should have been `!=`, not `-ne`... `-ne` is for arithmetic inequality.

Comment: Yes, I will edit it accordingly. Thanks for the update.

Comment: @Kusalananda, not the `echo`, the assignment to `retries`, it's last in the condition list.

Comment: @ilkkachu So it is.

Answer (score 1):

```
sleep $(( 1^$retries * 1))
```

This probably doesn't do what you want. [`^` is bitwise xor](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Arithmetic.html#Shell-Arithmetic), so you'd get um, well, 1, 0, 3, 2, etc... Exponentiation is `**`. And also of course `1**X` is just `1`, and `X*1` is just `X`, but you were probably meaning to fix the constants later.